# отображение Bootstrap Tooltip в svg

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Добрый день!

Не могу разобраться. На сайте есть модальное окно, в котором есть svg изображение. Мне нужно отобразить подсказки при наведении на полигоны в svg.
Плагин подключаю так:

```
$('polygon').tooltip({container: '#svg-inner svg g', html: true})
```

В результате при каждом наведении на полигон создаётся новый слой

```
<div class="tooltip fade top" role="tooltip" id="tooltip828254" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block;">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner">Подсказка</div>
</div>
```

Который затем удаляется. Саму подсказку не видно. Как отловить такую ситуацию?

Bootstrap 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Починил.
Дело в том, что когда **BS Tooltip** используется для модального окна - **container** для этого tooltip lолжен быть именно этот **modal-content**, на которые tooltip должен реагировать. В моём случае:

```
$('polygon').tooltip({container: '#sector .modal-content', html: true})
```